# Is there a method in angularJS thats equal to getJSON. [Newbie alert]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, syntax-error, getjson

I'm newbie at javascript, angularJS and JQuery, but I have just started programming a angularJS app where i use JQuery to get a JSON from a webserver like this:

```
var obj = $.getJSON( "http://something.com/lol?query="+ $scope.searchString, function() {
            $scope.items = obj.responseJSON.entries;                    
        }
```

Is there a method equal to $.getJSON in angularJS? So that I don't have to import the JQuery library.

Thanks in advance, newbie.

This is my solution so far:

```
function InstantSearchController($scope, $http){
 $scope.search = function() {   
  $http.jsonp("http://something.com/lol?query="+ $scope.searchString + "?json_callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success(
                        function(data, status) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                );
 }
```

but I'm getting the error msg:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

why is this? what am I doing wrong?
    }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of the help i got from people answering my question I finally managed to fix it, and i did it like this:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.items = [];  
     $scope.search = function() {        
            $http({method: 'JSONP', url: "http://something.com/lol?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&query="+ $scope.searchString}).
              success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.items = data.entries;
              }).
              error(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data || "Request failed");
            });     
     };
```

Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem in the future :D

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) to send AJAX requests in Angular.

Answer (score 2):

You may use JSONP requests with $http.jsonp

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

Answer (score 1):

```
function ListProdcutsCtrl($scope, $http) {
    var request = {'searchString' : 'apple'};
    $http.get('/api/products', request).success(function(response) {
        $scope.products_table_data = response.products;
    });
```

Comment: var request = {'searchString' = 'apple'}; ? it should be var request = {'searchString' : 'apple'};

Comment: I don't understand this, because of the different setup aaaand that I'm a complete noooob... Is it possible to give me a solution with the same names i Used in my example? xD

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative in AngularJS called `$http`, you can find [more here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).
For instance :

```
$http({method: 'JSONP', url: 'http://domain.com/page?json_callback=JSON_CALLBACK'}).success(
    function(data, status) {
        // your stuff.
    }
);
```

Or even shorter :

```
$http.jsonp('http://domain.com/page?json_callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(
    function(data, status) {
        // your stuff.
    }
);
```

JSONP (JSON Padding) allows you to get JSON data from another domain. However, the data you get should not be plain JSON, but rather a Javascript file like this :

```
JSON_CALLBACK([
    {"name": "apple", "color": "red"},
    {"name": "banana", "color": "yellow"}
]);
```

If your JSON data you need comes from the same domain, you do not need JSONP.

Comment: Thanks! But thats a JSONP and not JSON? Whats the difference? I'm getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" error when I'm doing this, is that probably why?

Comment: JSONP allows various browser to request JSON data from another domain, something usually forbidden by browsers. Though in my sample url it is not explicit, you need to add parameter "callback=JSON_CALLBACK" to your URL (more info in AngularJS doc).

Comment: I tried pasting my code here, but dident get it to work, so i extended my question. Any idea whats wrong? feel like a huuuuge noob now, been at it for ours!

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is used to overcome the cross-domain restriction of the AJAX URL calls.

With AngularJS (v1.5), you can use this code to send cross domain requests:

```
$http.jsonp(baseurl+'?token=assume_jwt_token'+encoding+type + "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
```

The Syntax for AngularJS JSONP request is :

```
$http.jsonp(url, [config]);
```

where url is "string" type representing Relative or absolute URL specifying the destination of the request. The name of the callback should be the string JSON_CALLBACK, and [config] is Optional configuration object.