# $.getJSON call from angular.element(document).ready or initController

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following snippet to get the data from server to load the initial content of the page.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['UserService', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$cookieStore', 'AuthenticationService'];
function MyController(UserService, $rootScope, $scope, $cookieStore, AuthenticationService) {


    /*Discussion Board related Functions*/ 
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        // Get Current User
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
        $scope.currentUser = AuthenticationService.GetAuthData($rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata);

        $.getJSON(
        "http://localhost/getSomeServerData.php",               
        { userName: $scope.currentUser },   
        $scope.getSomeDataResponse                                      
        );
    });

    $scope.getSomeDataResponse = function (jason) {
        var servRet = jason;
        alert("On Load Called-2");
    };
}
```

})();

However, the response function $scope.getSomeDataResponse is not getting called.

Please let me know what is wrong with this approach.

Comment: Have you checked your Console? Don't you see any errors regarding XMLHttpRequest cannot load or similar?

Comment: As some pointed out in answers (e.g. @NLN), you are not following some good practices, but your code should still work if you fix as I pointed out in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to define your result function before using. 
Second, you have to use $.getJSON correctly. So this worked for me after fixing

```
    $scope.getSomeDataResponse = function (jason) {
        var servRet = jason;
        alert("On Load Called-2");
    };

/*Discussion Board related Functions*/ 
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        // Get Current User
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
        $scope.currentUser = AuthenticationService.GetAuthData($rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata);

        $.getJSON(
        "http://localhost/getSomeServerData.php",               
        { userName: $scope.currentUser }

        ).always($scope.getSomeDataResponse);
```

the callback method was different in jQuery. use fail and done callbacks by looking at the jQuery documentation
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: There is nothing wrong or "incorrect" in OP's use of `$.getJSON`

Comment: Thank you for helping me in this. I am a Beginner in Web Dev (less than a month). Hence doing pity mistakes.  To some extent, I agree with @NLN. I will try to make my code better. Cheers ! ! !

Comment: @davidkonrad you are right. You can provide a success handler but if the call fails, the OP is not getting anything called, OP wants that alert to always pop up

Comment: @Braim, there is no statement in OP saying "_getSomeDataResponse should be called on error_" or similar, the problem was that `getSomeDataResponse` was never called at all. Your `always()` is a meaningless addendum since it is not backed up by error handling - the result is, that the success handler is called **even** if errors occur!! This can affect all aspects of the app. In 3 months time OP have to find out why an error occur, he will spent hours until he realizes that it is the JSON that fails - code he trusted - but your `always()` have prevented him from discover the error properly.

Comment: @davidkonrad you have a point, that is why I advised him to use done & fail callbacks according to API doco for his Prod code. But I agree with you , I should have not been lazy and implement both methods. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> However, the response function $scope.getSomeDataResponse is not
>   getting called.
>
> Please let me know what is wrong with this approach.

The issue is, you are referencing getSomeDataResponse before it is being declared. Also, you are using **jQuery's** `getJSON()` to get the  data from server using HTTP GET request in your **angularJS** code.

This is particularly not a recommended practise. If you include jQuery in your page, AngularJS will use jQuery instead of jqLite when wrapping elements within your directives, *otherwise* it'll delegable to jqLite(which might not work in all cases). To be at a safer side, use angular's `$http.get()` service instead of `$.getJSON()`

```
$http.get("http://localhost/getSomeServerData.php",{ userName: $scope.currentUser})
     .then(function(jason){
           //success handler function
           var servRet = jason;
           alert("On Load Called-2");
           },function(err){
             //error handler function
             alert(err);
          })
```

Ofcourse you'd need to inject `$http` service in your controller to make it work. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356841/is-there-a-method-in-angularjs-thats-equal-to-getjson-newbie-alert) thread for other possible alternatives.

Cheers!

Comment: While not good practice, but $.getJSON should still work. The OP is not asking what is the equivalent of $.getJSON in angular or best practices of calling a RESTful service in angular.

Comment: This is so immature of you. His code looks fine otherwise, the only possible reason could be $.getJSON being incompatible with angularJS version. Did he mention the angularJS version he used ? Or weather he even used jQuery or not.

Comment: Sorry you didn't like my comment. I just pointed out that this line from start of your answer was not true. Quote:  "The issue is, you are using jQuery's getJSON() to get the data from server using HTTP GET request in your angularJS code". 
I just got his code working with latest of both.

Comment: If you edit and remove the wrong statement I can remove the negative vote

Comment: Hi NLN, Thank you for the details. I will use this info to make my code better. Thanks again ! ! !.