# Angular 1.7 binding data issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn about the binding mechanism in Angular 1.7 so I set up an easy example.

In this example it is the intention to print a `h4` element for each Product-name.

**JSON-file of my products (dummy.json)**

```
{
    "ProductName": "Test Product 1",
    "QuantityPerUnit": "100"
}, {
    "ProductName": "Test Product 2",
    "QuantityPerUnit": "10"
}, {
    "ProductName": "Test Product 3",
    "QuantityPerUnit": "25"
}
```

In my ProductController I want to bind my JSON-data to `$scope.products`

**ProductController.js**

```
angular.module("angularApp", [])
    .controller("ProductController", function ($scope) {

        $.getJSON("./dummy.json", function (json) {
            $scope.products = json;
        });

    });
```

In my HTML I do following things to make the binding work:

1. define the application `ng-app="angularApp"`
2. define the controller in the body-tag `ng-controller="ProductController"`
3. I want to loop through my products via `ng-repeat="product in products"` and I'm using the data-binding notation Angular says I have to use `{{ }}`

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="angularApp" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Angular 1.7.8 -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/ProductController.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="ProductController">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="list-group">
                <h4 ng-repeat="product in products">{{ product.ProductName }}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The console isn't showing any errors and when I'm checking my developer tools (AngularJS Batarang), I notice that at my body-tag my `products` exist.

What am I forgetting or doing wrong? 
Any pointing in the right direction is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `*ngFor`  instead of `ng-repeat` . `ngFor="let product of products;`  . `ng-repeat` is used in Angular 1.x

Comment: You mean AngularJS 1.7 not Angular 7? your question is confusing.

Comment: thanks, I adjust my question right away

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue or not, however you should use `$http` to get the json and not use jQuery's `$.getJSON`.  Many times when using external libraries, angulars change detection doesn't update the values as it should as Angular is aware of changes outside of its own code.  [Stackoverflow: Is there a method in angularJS thats equal to getJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356841/is-there-a-method-in-angularjs-thats-equal-to-getjson-newbie-alert)

Comment: @MichaelLynch thanks, I'll keep that in mind, but for now it is really just to be able and display the data :)

Comment: your JSON isn't valid. You need to put in inside of an array `[]`. Try to console.log the json you did fetch. Or put a `<pre>{{ products | json }}</pre>` in your view to debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First issue is the JSON file: it is not an array.

Should be like this:

```
[{
    "ProductName": "Test Product 1",
    "QuantityPerUnit": "100"
 }, {
    "ProductName": "Test Product 2",
    "QuantityPerUnit": "10"
 }, {
    "ProductName": "Test Product 3",
    "QuantityPerUnit": "25"
 }]
```

And as in the comments not sure why you are using $getJson, but this should work:

```
angular.module("angularApp", [])
    .controller("ProductController", function ($scope,$http) {   
        $http.get("dummy.json").then(function(response) {
          console.log("Json",response.data);
          $scope.products = response.data;
        });
});
```

With the Angular JS http you should be able to get the data, but you must inject the $http.

Here you can find also an [`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/FmWkvjGwCfED5rAnN2c1?p=preview)